# How to register on Drupal from another site using Jquery XML-RPC user.register? And how to reference drupal custom fields?

Tags: jquery, drupal-7, xml-rpc, ckan

I'm trying to register on drupal via ckan registering form using XML-RPC.
I added a custom field to drupal form (field_full_name), but the request didn't work because of the custom name that Drupal gave to the custom field -> field_full_name[und][0][value]
For Instance, when I send a request to Drupal with common values such as (name,mail or pass) the registration works.

This works :

```
$.xmlrpc({
    url: '/site/xmlrpc.php',
    methodName: 'user.register',
    params: [{name: $('#field-username').val(), mail: $('#field-email').val(), pass: $('#field-password').val()}],

    success, error etc...
```

But when I send a request to Drupal with the fullname value which corresponds to my custom field in Drupal the registration doesn't work.

This doesn't work :

```
$.xmlrpc({
    url: '/site/xmlrpc.php',
    methodName: 'user.register',
    params: [{name: $('#field-username').val(), mail: $('#field-email').val(), pass: $('#field-password').val(), field_full_name[und][0][value]: $('#field-fullname').val()}] 

    success, error etc...
```

I also tried :

```
$.xmlrpc({
    url: '/site/xmlrpc.php',
    methodName: 'user.register',
    params: [{name: $('#field-username').val(), mail: $('#field-email').val(), pass: $('#field-password').val(), field_full_name: $('#field-fullname').val()}]
```

'#field-username' '#field-password' '#field-fullname' are id's from ckan registration form.

The request doesn't work because of the "name" attribute of  element that Drupal gives to custom field, this doesn't fit in the request whereas common field like 'name or mail' does.

How to reference custom user fields?
Which name should I use in params instead of field_full_name?

How can I fill custom field with custom data by using services XML-RPC service?

Answer (score 1):

The right code is in fact this one :

```
$.xmlrpc({
    url: '/site/xmlrpc.php',
    methodName: 'user.register',
    params: [{name: $('#field-username').val(), mail: $('#field-email').val(), pass: $('#field-password').val(), field_full_name: {und: {0: {value: $('#field-fullname').val()}}}}],
```